# Math function while echo from extern text file

Tags: javascript, php, html

This is my form where I send rating information to my textfile.txt.

```
<form name="Star" id="Star">    
    <div id="rating-area" class="shadow">   

    <img src="star-icon.png" id="thumb1" data-value="1" />
    <img src="star-icon.png" id="thumb2" data-value="2" />
    <img src="star-icon.png" id="thumb3" data-value="3" />
    <img src="star-icon.png" id="thumb4" data-value="4" />
    <img src="star-icon.png" id="thumb5" data-value="5" />

    </div>

</form>
<script>


   jQuery('div#rating-area img').click(function(e){
        var val = jQuery(this).data('value') ;
        console.log(val) ;
        jQuery.post('post.php',{ Star : val },function(data,status){
            console.log('data:'+data+'/status'+status) ;
        }) ;
    }) ;

</script>
```

And this is my php call:

```
<?php

    $file = file("textfile.txt");
    $file_content = file_get_contents("textfile.txt");
    $file_content_separated_by_dash = explode("-", $file_content);


    echo "Number of votes in file: " . count($file_content_separated_by_dash) . "<br>";
    $sum = 0;

    foreach ($file_content_separated_by_dash as $vote) {
        $sum = $sum + $vote;
    }
    echo "Total: " . $sum;
?>
```

I don't seems to get the hang of this. When I run the progress to count number of votes in the textfile.txt I do only get the first vote as the total sum. No matter if I reload the page or not. It's still that very first vote that shows up. I've checked the textfile.txt. It updates itself whenever the "star-rating" is "onclick".

As well the "number of votes". To see how many times someone has clicked on it. It stays on 1 through the whole time.
What have I missed?

Im still quite a newbie with php. So if I forget any necassary information please tell me and I will try to update the post with that info.

Comment: share the content of text-file..

Comment: I uploaded the textfile.txt further below. The numbers that are inside is a result of me clicking some stars:)

Comment: where did you uploaded?

Comment: http://www.speedyshare.com/Ak6Rh/textfile.txt
Another comment from the answer category.

Comment: your textfile doesn't contain any '-'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your textfile content doesn't match with code.
Numbers in textfile must be separated with `-` to work the current code..

If you cant modify your Textfile insertion then change the reading code like this

```
<?php

    $file = file("textfile.txt");
    $file_content = file_get_contents("textfile.txt");
    $file_content_separated_by_dash = str_split($file_content);


    echo "Number of votes in file: " . count($file_content_separated_by_dash) . "<br>";
    $sum = 0;

    foreach ($file_content_separated_by_dash as $vote) {
        $sum = $sum + intval($vote);
    }
    echo "Total: " . $sum;
?>
```

Comment: don't forget to change variable names with suitable once.. $file_content_separated_by_dash is no more needed as you don't have any '-'.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your `textfile.txt` file? Code seems okay, need to check how data is being saved in text file.

Your file doesn't have -, it has only numbers.

so you can Use this code

```
$numbers = file_get_contents("textfile.txt");

$count =  strlen($numbers);
echo 'Total votes'.$count;

for($i = 0; $i < count; $i++) {
   echo $numbers[$i] . '<br />';
}
```

Comment: That's not an answer.

Comment: Yes of course, but, it's empty. Only the numbers that are saved is stored inside it.

Comment: http://www.speedyshare.com/Ak6Rh/textfile.txt

As you can see, only the numbers are saved.

Comment: @hindmost yes I know its not answer but I can't add comment, need more points :)

Comment: @Winterwind, You are exploding with "-" but file doesn't have any "-" so explode will return whole data to array "$file_content_separated_by_dash" and array will have only one index. Count will return 1. Read more about explode here http://pk1.php.net/explode. If you store data like 1-2-3-4-5-3-4-4-5-8, you will get correct result with explode

Comment: Is it possible to edit this through the script code that inset the numbers? Or is it any way around it?

Comment: When you get file content its a array string. See my code below.      $count =  strlen($numbers);
echo  "Number of votes in file: " . $count; 
 
 for($i = 0; $i < count; $i++) {
    echo $numbers[$i] . '<br />';
 }

Comment: As I wrote, no need to call str_split function, file_get_contents returns content as array string. See my code above :)